# Консольное приложение и пути с дополнительными точками

Tags: c#, cmd

Необходимо консольной программе передать путь до файла. Проблема заключается в том, что в пути, имена папок содержат дополнительные точки. Например C:/papka1/pap.rrr.ttt/papka2/. Пишу программу на C# которая запускает сторонние консольное приложение, которому передаёт два аргумента: первый - путь до файла, второй - дополнительный шифр (неважно). Если папка не содержит точек, все работает отлично. Подскажите кто-нибудь как решить данную задачу.

Пример кода:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "путь до программы";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "путь до файла"; 
proc.Start();
```

Comment: А путь в двойные кавычки обернуть не поможет?

Comment: @MBo Нет, не поможет.

Comment: @MBo Уже делал, не помогло

Comment: А что при этом передаётся консольной программе?

Comment: @MBo путь до файла с расширением .cls (текстовый файл)

Comment: Так какой путь доходит  до консольной программы, если ей передать такой, как указан? Можно для проверки свою консольную запускать.

Comment: @MBo не могу посмотреть, так как вызываемая из моей программа написана не мной. Но есть подозрения, что доходя до первой точки в имени папки, она эту папку считает файлом.

Comment: @MBo Например путь C:/papka1/pap.rrr.ttt/papka2/files.txt он создает мне файл с именем pap.txt, а должен файл остаться с таким же именем.

Comment: @AntonPomazkov выведите в консоль `Console.WriteLine(proc.StartInfo.Arguments);` -  что там лежит ?

Answer (score 0):

Нет никакой проблемы, пожалуйста:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("my.com.test");
File.WriteAllText("my.com.test\\test.txt", "Hello world");
var data = File.ReadAllText("my.com.test\\test.txt");
Console.WriteLine(data);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Я правильно понял в консоль выведется "Hello world"? Мне же надо передать из моего приложения сторонему консольному приложению путь, например (my.com.test\\test.txt). Но когда это делаю оно работает некорректно. Если передаю путь без точек, все ОК.

Comment: @AntonPomazkov так передавайте, косяк в вашем коде не в консоли, что доказывает приведённый пример. Где вообще код ? как вы передаёте аргументы ? что из себя представляет путь относительно приложения которому вы передаёте ?

Comment: Запускаю сторонние приложение и путь передаю так:        
'ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
procInfo.FileName = "путь до программы"
procInfo.Arguments = "путь до файла";
Process.Start();'

Comment: Так же побывал запускать приложение без участия своего, напрямую то есть.  Она так де не воспринимает пути с точками. Так что дело не в моем приложении.

Comment: @AntonPomazkov отредактируйте свой вопрос, добавьте в него код.

Answer (score 0):

Сделать свою консольную программу, и проверить, что при её вызове такой путь доходит верно.

Если проблема в том, что принимающая программа не может корректно обработать такой путь, то можно сформировать короткое имя (функция `GetShortPathName`  в шарпе доступна?)

Comment: Попробую завтра испытать, спасибо за помощь. Надеюсь получится. Если нет, тогда буду перед запуском перемещать нужный файл в директорию где в именах папок не используются точки. А после исполнения стороне программы, возвращать на место.